# how to apply a directive to a element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have created a directive that displays a table. When user clicks on a cell in the table it gets activated. I am also trying to permit movement between cells i.e when you click on a particular cell and press the right arrow key, the cell next to it should get selected.

I am kind of stuck on how to activate the directive on the adjacent cells.

anyone any idea on how to implement this :

plnkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YyZLVKtRAR1OYGey0FYj

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) and `.focus()` to accomplish this.

For example, you could do something like this to move right:

```
$('input[select-me][row=' + row + '][col=' + (parseInt(col, 10) + 1) + ']').focus();
```

You will likely want something a bit more sophisticated to handle being the last column in the row, but you get the idea.

Comment: rtcherry.. thanks for the suggestion.. not quite sure how I would apply this in a angular directive

Comment: You already have code that logs out the current row/column when you push the right arrow...  You could use this in place of that to perform the action (although using jQuery in a controller is not a great practice).  I would suggest reading the documentation and samples for creating directives.